# Cannot push to github with SSH

Tags: github

I'm trying to follow the steps recommended here:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

```
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "bobsmith202@hotmail.com"
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/bobsmith/.ssh/id_ed25519): skey
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in skey.
Your public key has been saved in skey.pub.

The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:zzzzzzzzzzzzpbpcHTQ5cDcKqSne8 bobsmith202@hotmail.com   (altered of course)
The key's randomart image is:

[deleted]
```

However when I run

```
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ls ~/.ssh
authorized_keys
authorized_keys copy
config
google_compute_engine
google_compute_engine.pub
google_compute_known_host original
google_compute_known_hosts
google_compute_known_hosts original copy
google_compute_known_hosts_copy
known_hosts
known_hosts copy
known_hosts original
kyle_aws_key.pem
ssh_key
ssh_key copy
ssh_key.pub
ssh_key.pub copy
ssh_key1
ssh_key1.pub
```

The file is not there.

I was not able to get the ssh-add command to work but I don't think that matters.

```
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
/Users/bobsmith/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/skey
/Users/bobsmith/.ssh/skey: No such file or directory
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/skey
/Users/bobsmith/.ssh/skey: No such file or directory
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ open ~/.ssh
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/skey.pub
/Users/bobsmith/.ssh/skey.pub: No such file or directory
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/skey
ssh-add: illegal option -- -
```

I could not generate the ssh key so I used:

```
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ cat skey.pub
ssh-ed25519 [deleted]
```

That generated the ssh key, but again I don't understand why the file skey.pub does not exist in the ssh file

I then posted the key into the proper place in my gihub account.  When I run

```
(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/skey.pub
-bash: /Users/bobsmith/.ssh/skey.pub: No such file or directory

(venv3) Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:learn_git bobsmith$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.3' to the list of known hosts.
no such identity: /Users/bobsmith/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

And at that point I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking in the folder `/Users/bobsmith/.ssh` ?

Comment: I wrote that when I run `ls ~/.ssh` the desired file does not appear and as far as I know ~ = /users/bobsmith on my computer.  I'm able to generate the ssh key however which is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

They don't make it clear on the instructions that you have to

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

Before you run

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```